# How to parse a text file into two parts using Scanner

Tags: java

Input (white space delimited):

```
1 1 2 3
2 1 7
3 3 7
4 1 5
5 3 6
```

I would like to process these input as like:

For each line in the text file :: (first_element, e.g. 1) into an int variable (say, m) and the following (next_elements, e.g. 1 2 3) into an ArrayList (say, N)

I tried the below:

```
Scanner file_scanner = new Scanner(filename);
  while (file_scanner.hasNextLine()) {              
     String[] line = file_scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
     String str1 = line[0];
     String str2 = line[1];

     m = Integer.parseInt(str1);

     Scanner line_scanner = new Scanner(str2);
     while(line_scanner.hasNext()) {
        int n = line_scanner.nextInt();
        N.add(n);
     }
  }
```

But I am not able to parse the inputs as I intended to. Any kind suggestions on how to handle two parts of an input line using Scanner? or, even how to check the end of the current line (EOL) as well as how to parse the first element more easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `String[] line = file_scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+",2);` in your code. It will split each line into 2 tokens only.

EDIT: line[1] will contain the rest of the numbers, you do not need to parse it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! it saves my life for now :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it might not be the most efficient since it's 4:39 am:

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
    int m  = 0;
    List<Integer> list = null;

    while(s.hasNextLine())
    {
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(s.nextLine());
        int count = 0;

        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (s2.hasNextInt())
        {

            if(count == 0)
            {
                m = s2.nextInt();
            }
            else
            {
                list.add(s2.nextInt());
            }
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(m + " " + list);
    }
```